# See state of file at revision in Subversion?

Tags: svn, diff

I deleted a file from Subversion. I don't want it back, but I want to see what it looked like at a revision.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Either pass a specific revision to "svn update" (or "svn checkout") on a working copy that would have contained that file at the revision passed. E.g. `svn update -r123`; OR pass a specific revision to `svn cat` in similar fashion to extract the file contents directly from the repository without a working copy. Using `svn cat` you may need to use a "peg revision" so that SVN looks at the folder structure at that given revision as well, so that it can actually find the file. E.g. `svn cat http://example.com/svn/file.txt@123`